# Symfony Doctrine - In a many to many relation why is the patch working in one direction but not the other

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I'm on a project where I have a many to many relationship between team and agent. Because my teams can have multiple agents and my agents can have multiple teams.

I'm in a situation where I'm doing a patch so I can add multiple agents to a team (which is working) but I cannot do a working patch to add multiple teams to an agent.

Is it because of mapped by and inversed by?

**UPDATE**

In my *TEAM* entity here is the relation

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Agent", inversedBy="teams")
 */
private $agents;
```

Here is the relation in my *AGENT* entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Team", mappedBy="agents")
 */
private $teams;
```

In my team controller, when I want to give my team some new agents I'm using this piece of code and it works. I can see all the agents associated to the team in the database.

`$team->setAgents($theAgents);`

But when I want to do the opposite in my **agent controller** (assigning some teams to a new agent) the agent is created in the database but it's not assigned to any team in the association table. Even if I'm using this:
    `$agent->setTeams($theTeams);`

Hence, is it maybe because it's not possible with Doctrine? Or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you show us the code please ?

Comment: Why do you say you cannot? both should be possible.

Comment: if you can not it's probably because your algorithm to do it has a problem. show us the code so we can help

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your answers, I tried to update my problem as you told me!

Comment: @Frabot If I understand correctly, one of your field is set to NULL in the generated many to many table in your database? Have you tried using cascade={"persist"} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution I found is similar to Jannes'.

In my Agent entity I added this function:

```
 /**
 * @param mixed $team
 */
public function addTeam(Team $team)
{
    $this->teams[] = $team;
    $team->addAgent($this);
}
```

and in my Agent controller:

```
$teams = $request->get('teams');
foreach ($teams as $team){
   $myTeam = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Team')
            ->find($team["id"]);
   $agent->addTeam($myTeam);
}
```

By doing so, I was I able to have a working post on both sides!
Thank you all again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This is the **expected behavior**.

For your ManyToMany relation you have the **owning side**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Agent", inversedBy="teams")
*/
private $agents;
```

and the **inverse side**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Team", mappedBy="agents")
*/
private $teams;
```

which are defined by the settings **inversedBy** and **mappedBy** respectively.

For a [ManyToMany relation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association), you can chose which entity is the owning and which the inverse side, either of them can be defined.

Doctrine **only checks the owning side** for association changes. Check [Working with associations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts), which means on your case, only $agents of Teams is checked for any changes to be persisted in the database.

On Agents, any changes in teams are ignored.

> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored. Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at least the owning side, from Doctrine's point of view)

It is your responsibility to include these changes on the owning side also.

So in **setTeams**, do something like:

```
public function setTeams($teams) {
    $this->teams = $teams;
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $team->addAgent($this);
    }
}
```

Note that in **addAgent** you have to check if the agent already exists in the collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I used a solution similar in the end!  In my controller I added /**
     * @param mixed $team
     */
    public function addTeam(Team $team)
    {
        $this->teams[] = $team;
        $team->addAgent($this);
    } and then did the foreach in my controller! I think I didn't understand this side of the Many to Many relation but now I see!